# Filter pandas dataframe to get desired output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I have a dataframe having data as below.

```
index   col1    col2
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   c
3   2   a
4   2   b
5   2   c
6   3   a
7   3   b
8   3   c
```

Need data as below. I tried getting this output using for loop but its taking lot of time as there are almost 1 million records. Please suggest some good logic using pandas functions

```
col1    col2
   1       a
   2       b
   3       c
```

---

```
col1ids= []
col2ids= []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col1'] in(col1ids) or row['col2'] in(col2ids):
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
    else:
        col1ids.append(row['col1'])
        col2ids.append(row['col2'])
```

Yes just 2 columns and pattern is not same for all rows. There are many rows with just 1:1

```
Col1            Col2
0700225821  461605030
0700225821  461605029
0700225822  461605030
0700225822  461605029
0700225826  461605031
0700225826  461605033
0700225824  461605031
0700225824  461605033
0700281780  437328994
0700199984  440669675
```

Comment: What is the logic to get to your expected output? I can _guess_ but it's unlikely to hold for your 1M records...

Comment: Read about drop_duplicates function.

Comment: I added two list, one to hold values from col 1 that are already looped over and another for col2. If any of the col1 or col2 value is repeating then i am deleting it from dataframe. I am not able to achieve this using drop duplicates

Comment: @sn1986 your problem statement is not clear. Please update your question with a proper explanation justifying your output. Also it is a good practice to post what you have tried as the comment above says.

Comment: I think OP solved the problem with a loop, but couldn't find a logic to solve it with another method. IMO, this is an interesting problem.

Comment: I have added working code

Comment: Can you give more details on the real dataset? 2 columns? Are the rows periodic like in the example? What types? Etc. Ideally a small extract would be nice.

Comment: Added some data

Comment: Please change your input sample, it's probably too simple. I feel you can just use  `df['col1'].unique()` and df['col2'].unique() and that's all.

Comment: I am getting following error  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Tried change like this df=df((df.col1.unique() and df.col2.unique()))

Comment: added some more sample data